# Run script on showing iframe content

Tags: javascript, events, iframe

I have a hidden iframe (via style `display:none`), which contains input fields to enter username/password combination that must be checked on other resource. Is it possible to automatically focus input field in the iframe when the iframe is shown?

Sample: 
http://0x49d1.azurewebsites.net/logintest.php

Comment: How are you displaying the iframe? With javascript? Show the code, please.

Comment: @MariusStanescu added a sample for the call. Im using jQuery there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try binding to the attribute with a library like this:

http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/

or as these posts suggest: [jquery bind change css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180812/jquery-bind-change-css)

Or as others have suggested just add the handler in whatever shows it.

Comment: Seems not the thing i want here. I need to focus(for example) element inside of iframe and not the form the iframe is loaded in.

Comment: Might need a server side component to call out and handle it that way I don't know if you can do it in purely js

Comment: i think so too. Will try to catch some visibility events on elements inside of iframe's content generator.

Comment: In the end i've made it via callback from client to using shared object to listen to special events. So i think your answer is the closest.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myIframe').on('show', function() {
      $("#usernameFieldID").focus();
});
```

Comment: This is not working, because i need to focus element inside of iframe, not inside the parent form, where the frame is hosted.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery has the concept of custom events. You can write an extender for Jquery and then interface with it using the .show/.hide methods.

For further info check this out.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-trigger-custom-event-show-hide-element/